# Is there a way to set middleware in express (node.js) to have specific values return in every route?

Tags: json, node.js, express

The situation that I am specifically referring to involves the use of json web tokens (jwt). For example how would I automatically add middleware to only return a new json web token if that web token is expired without duplicating code?  The sample code below will show what I mean.

```
var express = require("express");
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var router = express.Router();


router.use(function(req,res,next){
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token,"secretTingz",{algorithms:["RS256"]},function(err,decoded){
            if (err) {
                if (token.expired) {
                    // HOW DO I GET THIS PIECE OF CODE TO RUN FOR EVERY VALID ROUTE THAT NEEDS A NEW TOKEN WITHOUT DUPLICATING CODE?
                    var token = jwt.sign({user:"MilnerJenkins"},cert,{algorithm:"RS256",expiresInMinutes:1});
                    req.token = token;
                    next();
                }else{
                    return res.json({message:"Failed to authenticate token"});
                }
            }else{
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(403).send({
            message: "No token!"
        });
    }
});

apiRoutes.get("/stuff",function(req,res){
    var token;
    if (req.token) {
        token = req.token;
    };
    res.json({message: "Dope API son!",token:token});
});

apiRoutes.get("/users",function(req,res){
    var token;
    if (req.token) {
        token = req.token;
    };
    User.find({},function(err,users){
        res.json({users: users, token: token});
    });
});
```

As you can see code is being duplicated in both routes with this block:

```
var token;
if (req.token) {
    token = req.token;
};
```

What can I do with express middleware to prevent this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this with a "middleware" is by having a handler at the end of your middlware chain that would send the response. That would mean all your handlers would have to pass the request and response down the chain. It would essentially be the last handler before your 404 handler. I do not recommend attempting that. Alternatively you can create a custom response method for your express app.

```
var app = require('express')();

app.response.myJsonRes = function(obj) {
    if (this.req.token) {
        obj.token = this.req.token;
    }
    this.json(obj);
};

app.get('/myRoute', function(req, res) {
   // get data somehow
   res.myJsonRes(data);
});
```

You coulld even change the standard `json` method.

```
var prevJson = app.response.json;
app.response.json = function(obj) {
    if (this.req.token) {
       obj.token = this.req.token;
    }
    prevJson.call(this, obj);
};
```